# Maximum number of characters in a field of a csv file using unix shell commands?

Tags: unix, command-line, csv, text-processing

I have a csv file.  In one of the fields, say the second field, I need to know maximum number of characters in that field.  For example, given the file below:

```
adf,jlkjl,lkjlk
jf,j,lkjljk
jlkj,lkejflkj,adfafef,
jfje,jj,lkjlkj
jjee,eeee,ereq
```

the answer would be 8 because row 3 has 8 characters in the second field.  I would like to integrate this into a bash script, so common unix command line programs are preferred.  Imaginary bonus points for explaining what the command is doing.

EDIT: Here is what I have so far

```
cut --delimiter=, -f 2 test.csv | wc -m
```

This gives me the character count for all of the fields, not just one, so I still have progress to make.

Comment: Well interesting problem which may be sloved with `cut` and `wc`... But for what do you need that?

Comment: @rekire thanks I did not know about cut.  That looks to be what I need to get started....

Comment: You may also look at `awk` the stream editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @oob, you basically provided the answer with your last edit, and it's the most simple of all answers given. However, I also like @Birei's answer just because I enjoy AWK. :-)

I too had to find the longest possible value for a given field inside a text file today. Tested with your sample and got the expected 8.

`cut -d, -f2 test.csv | wc -L`

As you see, just a matter of using the correct option for `wc` (which I hope you have already figured by now).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk` for the task. It uses a comma to split line in fields and for each line checks if the length of second field is bigger that the value already saved.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        FS = "," 
    } 
    { c = length( $2 ) > c ? length( $2 ) : c } 
    END { 
        print c 
    }
' infile
```

Use it as a one-liner and assign the return value to a variable, like:

```
num=$(awk 'BEGIN { FS = "," } { c = length( $2 ) > c ? length( $2 ) : c } END { print c }' infile)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to loop over the lines. Than I exchange the commas with new lines to loop over the *words* than I check which is the longest word and save the data.

```
#!/bin/bash

lineno=1
matchline=0
matchlen=0
for line in $(cat input.txt); do
        words=`echo $line | sed -e 's/,/\n/g'`
        for word in $words; do
#               echo "line: $lineno; length: ${#word}; input: $word"
                if [ $matchlen -lt ${#word} ]; then
                        matchlen=${#word}
                        matchline=$lineno
                fi
        done;
        lineno=$(($lineno + 1))
done;

echo max length is $matchlen in line $matchline
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Bash and Coreutils Solution

There are a number of ways to solve this, but I vote for simplicity. Here's a solution that uses Bash parameter expansion and a few standard shell utilities to measure each line:

```
cut -d, -f2 /tmp/foo |
while read; do
    echo ${#REPLY}
done | sort | tail -n1
```

The idea here is to split the CSV file, and then use the [parameter length expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) of the implicit *REPLY* variable to measure the characters on each line. When we sort the measurements, the last line of the sorted output will hold the length of the longest line found.

Answer (score 0):

1. cut out the desired column
2. print each line length
3. sort the line lengths
4. grab the max line length

`cut -d, -f2 test.csv | awk '{print length($0);}' | sort -n | tail -n 1`